# Backup of VM using "virsh snapshot-create-as" works once. Fails second time

Tags: backup, qemu

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with QEMU 4.2.1 and am trying to setup backups using these instructions:
https://libvirt.org/kbase/live_full_disk_backup.html (older libvirt instructions, as Ubuntu 20 has older libvirt).

The backup method works once, but fails when run a second time.  This may be related to the instructions using a VM that has the VM disk as a .raw file, but I'm using a .qcow2. At this point have several VMs, so I'd rather not convert to .raw.

When I run:

```
$ virsh snapshot-create-as --domain vm1 overlay1 \
    --diskspec vda,file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/overlay1.qcow2 \
    --disk-only
virsh blockcommit vm1 vda --active --verbose --pivot
```

Everything works, no errors.
If I don't remove the "overlay1.qcow2" file and run the command again, I get this error:

```
error: unsupported configuration: external snapshot file for disk vda already exists and is not a block device: /var/lib/libvirt/images/overlay1.qcow2
```

If I remove the file before running it again (as suggested by the instructions):

```
error: operation failed: domain moment overlay1 already exists
```

Did some digging and ran the snapshot-list:

```
$ virsh snapshot-list --tree vm1
overlay1
```

Tried removing the snapshot:

```
virsh snapshot-delete vm1 overlay1
error: Failed to delete snapshot overlay1
error: unsupported configuration: deletion of 1 external disk snapshots not supported yet
```

Not sure where to go from here.
Do I have to use .raw images?
. . If so, why?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help delete the snapshot? https://serverfault.com/a/722484/802321 . Also, in order to take a second snapshot, you need to provide virsh with a qcow2 image that does not exist. It will not overwrite the image file. file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/overlay1-snap1.qcow2 for example, should work.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that worked.  I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alex who provided a link that told me how to remove the snapshot metadata.

A working series of commands for VMs using .qcow2 images is:

```
$ virsh snapshot-create-as --domain vm1 overlay1 \
    --diskspec vda,file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/overlay1.qcow2 \
    --disk-only
(Insert your backup command here)
$ virsh blockcommit vm1 vda --active --verbose --pivot 
$ virsh snapshot-delete vm1 --metadata overlay1
$ rm -f /var/lib/libvirt/images/overlay1.qcow2
```